# Directly accessing Active Storage using Active Record query interface

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-activestorage

How do I do something like the following in Rails ActiveRecord

```
Select *
from active_storage_blobs
where checksum = '0M4nc4nuUaVuqo3+sJw+Lg=='
```

In other words `item = active_storage_blobs.find_by checksum: '0M4nc4nuUaVuqo3+sJw+Lg=='` but 
Rails doesn't know about `active_storage_blobs` as a table or model.

Use case: I am reusing images in different records which means they get uploaded and stored multiple times. So I want to check and see if the image has already been uploaded. I was planning on using the `checksum` and if it's already in storage, use its `id` with the new record.

Rails 6 with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's `ActiveStorage::Blob` model:

```rb
ActiveStorage::Blob.find_by(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. Not at a computer now. But sounds like it will work

Comment: Works:

    <%=  checksumFor49 = ActiveStorage::Blob.find(49).checksum %>
    <br>
    id: <%= id = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_by(checksum: checksumFor49).id  %> for checksumFor49

Result

    0M4nc4nuUaVuqo3+sJw+Lg==
    id: 49 for checksumFor49

Thanks